# Regex, one occurrence between two differents delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to have a regex which select everything between the not-included characters delimiters ``` and `I`. I only want the first occurrence.

Here is my wrong try (very new to regex) :

```
(^`)[\s\S](I$)?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/(?<=`).*?(?=I)/s
```

This regex will look for a backtick, but not include it. Then it will match anything it can, up to the first I character.

The difference between this answer and @vks's answer is that mine will *require* there to be an ending delimiter.